# Big-O estimation for $\frac{\log(\log(n^2+1)}{\log n}$

Tags: asymptotics

I think it should be like:

$=\dfrac{\log(\log(n^2+10))}{\log(n)}$

$=\dfrac{\log(2\log(n))}{\log(n)}$

$=\dfrac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)}$

But $\log(\log(n))<\log(n)$
As the $log(n)$ is in the denominator.

Hence it is $O(\log(\log(n)))$

Is it correct?

Comment: In fact, and more importantly, $\frac{\log(\log(n^2+1))}{\log(n)}$ is $O(1)$, in other words there exists a $C>0$ so that for all $n$ large enough, 
$$\frac{\log(\log(n^2+1))}{\log(n)} < C(1)$$

The fact it is $O(1)$ implies that it is $O(\log(\log(n))$ because $O(1) \subsetneq O(\log(\log(n))$,

Comment: The fact that this holds for any $C>0$ means that it is also $o(1)$.